# I wanna make To Do Android App with firebase on cloud google firebse tutorial. This js the error I got

Tags: android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is mybuild.gradle file.

```html
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bosnia.todoapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'

}
```

so i wanna make android to do app cloud based with firebase, And I have this error issue.

So the default code is `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` I replace it with `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` and this is the error code. And this is my error `Could not find method android() for arguments [build_e0nio0g58fflcu8rkqyodi904$_run_closure1@41701092] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Comment: Btw i just add 'apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'' in the top of the this line 'apply plugin: 'com.android.application'' and nothing error

Answer (score 0):

`'com.android.application'` is key plugin for you application. As per [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), you should add `'com.google.gms.google-services'` in your project and not replace.

Try following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bosnia.todoapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'

}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

add the `apply plugin com.google.gms....`
at the bottom of your app level build.gradle file